# Initialization makes integer from pointer without cast

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to define a struct with specific parameters but I'm wonder if there's a better way to initialize the struct **without using memory allocation**.

The struct definitions:

```
#define MAXLINE 1024
#define MAXNAME 256
#define MAXPATH 1024

typedef enum {
  BL_MESG         = 10

} mesg_kind_t;

// mesg_t: struct for messages between server/client
typedef struct {
  mesg_kind_t kind;               // kind of message
  char name[MAXNAME];             // name of sending client or subject of event
  char body[MAXLINE];             // body text, possibly empty depending on kind
} mesg_t;

typedef struct {
  char name[MAXPATH];
} client_t;
```

How I'm creating a msg_t

```
mesg_t create_mesg(client_t *client, char *text){
  char * cl_name = client->name;
  mesg_t msg = {BL_MESG, "", ""};
  strcpy(msg.name, cl_name);
  strcpy(msg.body, text);
  return msg;
}
```

Is there a way to initialize it without using strcpy? Is there something obvious that I'm just totally missing here?

Comment: That code does not have the error mentioned in the title. So either fix the title, or show the code you're asking about.

Comment: I couldn't set the connection between casting, memory allocation and strcpy. Can you be more specific? You want to initialize it dynamically? What exactly do you want to do? What is wrong with strcpy?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid memory allocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it this way. You need to use something which is passed and copied by value. In C it can be `struct` or `union`.

```
#define MAXLINE 1024
#define MAXNAME 256
#define MAXPATH 1024

typedef enum {
  BL_MESG         = 10
} mesg_kind_t;

struct names
{
    char name[MAXNAME];
};

struct bodys
{
    char body[MAXNAME];
};

typedef struct {
  char name[MAXPATH];
} client_t;



// mesg_t: struct for messages between server/client
typedef struct {
  mesg_kind_t kind;               // kind of message
  client_t name;             // name of sending client or subject of event
  struct bodys body;             // body text, possibly empty depending on kind
} mesg_t;

#define MAKENAME(str) (struct bodys){str}
#define MAKEBODY(str) (client_t){str}


mesg_t create_mesg(client_t *client, struct bodys text){

  mesg_t msg = {BL_MESG, *client, text};
  return msg;
}


void foo()
{
    create_mesg(&MAKEBODY("This is client"), MAKENAME("this is body"));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/d83USr